# Formatting SAS report through EG Report Builder

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am new to SAS and I'm starting out with EG. I am trying to add a border around several items in a report in order to group them into sections. For example in my [mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHpEJ.png)  three list reports are combined into one section on the left and 2 pie charts are combined to form another section on the right.

I know you can arrange tables and images through the modify report button in EG, but I would really like to be able to have borders around groups of related tables, or figures.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here (and I'm not sure how many EG-primary folks will be on SO, as opposed to base SAS users) you might try posting this on communities.sas.com - some SAS support folk read that forum and are more likely to be helpful on something like this.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I'll try that as well.